# How to review through the app

Tags: feature-request, support, android-app

Is there a way to review suggested edits, low quality posts, late answers, etc. through the Stack Exchange application?

If yes, please explain how.

If not, will this be considered as a feature request?

I am currently using the SE Android app.

Comment: @rene It has no answer.

Comment: @JaideepKhare it has no answer because it hasn't been implemented

Comment: @Cai So what next? Will this never be done.Suppse this gets marked as duplicate, then someone will come, open the original post from the link given....Whoa! It also doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Is that any better than having the same feature request over and over again?

Comment: As for whether it will be done, who knows. There's been no Android development for some time, but even then this is down to a limitation of the API and implementing a new review UI is no small task.

Comment: The android app is dead by all means, so yes, this will never be done.